# installation screen discription

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ubuntu-studio, audio-recording

I am trying to install ubuntu studio 20.04.5 from DVD to my second SSD which is on eSATA. I'm at the Installation Type Screen. I think I want to select dev/sdb not dev/sda. I don't know if I should choose boot or / or.... And I cant find any instructions. Can someone tell me or point me to the manual location? I can find some, but not describing this screen and its consequences.

I have win 7 and ubuntu 20.04 LTS on the internal SATAII drive and want to keep them. I think I want to keep the boot loader installation unchanged so the studio option gets added to the same grub screen but again thats guessing. should I format or partition first?

I want to minimize latencies for 4 track audio recording. I've seen mention of optimizing the ssd. does this need to be done before installation? is it better to install all 3 OSs on the same drive? I partitioned the internal drive in half for the 2 anticipated installations. If its better to have all 3 on it, do I have to start over? There is no second internal drive possible. The internal and external drive both seem to run around 300MB/s (SATAII and eSATA)(both 1TB ssd)

While the documentation is a little frustrating, everyone here has been very helpful and greatly appreciated. [pic of install type screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcy8M.jpg)

Comment: You are aware that Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS is EOL (https://ubuntustudio.org/2023/04/ubuntu-studio-20-04-has-reached-end-of-life/) and has no upgrade path either, as it was the last release that used the Xfce desktop (*thus you'll need to re-install in the future*).

Comment: No I didn't. that's just great :) I'd love to have installed the newer version, but as I can only install from a 4.7 GB DVD and even though several newer versions are listed as smaller, when I download them they are 4.8 GB!!!  and wont fit the DVD. maybe this torrent thing??? suggestions? If want to discuss USB, I spent a month trying to figure that out. And I'm pretty sure "not on my machine". You probably think "what a dummy" But I'd bet money.

Comment: Is there a way to use 4.7 DVD and get supported version?

Comment: is that true for ubuntu 22.04 LTS As well? I miss entered above I have win7 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on the internal drive. This works good for 2 track audio. I'm trying to get to 4 tracks and I suspect the Jack stuff may help. I tried installing Ubuntu Studio on the Ubuntu but that was a giant leap down the learning curve and nothing worked.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly I'd to and avoid installing from *optical* media (DVD) for any release beyond 20.04 as it was not intended media (*issues can be experienced, install is still possible but timeout issues on optical drive can cause misleading error messages during media checks for 20.10 & later*). You're free to install using whatever media you want, as you can always add `ubuntustudio-desktop` OR add it to any desktop in fact (see https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/)  https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/jammy/dvd/current/jammy-dvd-amd64.manifest shows packages on *jammy* ISO (*daily*)

Comment: You could always install like Xubuntu first which is a smaller distribution that will fit on a 4.7GB DVD.  Then you can use the Ubuntu Studio installer https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/ to install it over whatever distro you had installed.

Comment: so yes it looks like the only way. or I could use the unsupported version. I wanted to do a clean install because it work so poorly. It didn't download all that was checked and after I reinstalled those parts audio recording did not function usably. I thought that using old versions on old machines was the way to get the  best out of an old PC. are there performance issues like pops and dropouts when you use the newest version on old PCs? I will continue now just to get a stable, working install.

Comment: The oldest box I use in QA (*Quality Assurance* testing) is a HP branded box from 2005 (*though CPU was replaced & RAM upgraded many times since then*) but I don't create/edit audio! The main issue I encounter with newer software stacks relate to kernel stack & use of video cards (GPU) where often I find on older GPUs the older kernels are less problematic. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using HWE kernel stack (20.05.5) is the same as Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using the GA kernel stack (22.04 or 22.04.1 media); kernel stack set by install media for *flavors* like Ubuntu Studio.. ie. release is only part.